# Access code behind from ajax in asp.core 2.0

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

so I need to implement facebook authentication in asp.net core 2.0 mvc, which I already did. But then I need to access the code behind to perform database actions. I've done that before in classic asp.net but now in core I'm not so sure. I've implemented it before with an ajax function calling a web method function from code behind. Here, in mvc at least, the cs page is separate from the cshtml page. Is it still possible to do it?

Here's my code from the classic asp.net version:

```
// Client ajax function
function Ajax(expression1, expression2) {
        var request = { email: expression1, name: expression2}
        $.ajax({
            url: 'login.aspx/Login',
            method: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (resp) {
                window.location.href = resp.d;
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        })
    }

// Server side function that I needed to access

[WebMethod]
    public static string Login(string email, string name)
    {

        // Make required validations
        return whatever;
    }
```

So now I have the same but in the asp.net core 2.0 mvc way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. So, I have to put, in the url, the name of the controller, which in my case is 'Home', and the name of the method. In this case, it would be: 'Home/Login'. And in the code behind you can have just any function and it will work. But you have to receive the data to an object and the the tag (?) [FromBody] for it to work. For instance:

```
public string Login([FromBody]User user)
        {

        }
```

Yet, if there's an even better way I'm all ears. Thanks, anyway.